# Submit button redirect to another view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create submit button, which redirects me to to another view when I click on Accept.

I tried this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
           <input type="submit" value="Accept" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Index", "kupec") + "'");" class="btn btn-default"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

And this:

```
<input id="#redirect" type="submit" value="Accept" class="btn btn-default" />
```

with JavaScript:

```
$("#redirect").click(function () {
    document.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Dokument")';
});
```

However, neither of these two is working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are binding the click event to an element with Id `redirect`. But your button id is not `redirect` ,but `#redirect`( extra `#` prefix). remove that and it should work.

```
<input id="redirect" type="submit" value="Accept" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Also it might be a good idea to wrap your event handlers in the document ready event. If your button is inside a form element, it is a good idea to prevent the default form submit behavior as well.(*If you really don't want to submit the form, you should not keep it inside the form ! :)*)

```
$(function(){
  $("#redirect").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     document.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Dokument")';
  });
});
```

Comment: That code should work as long as you do not have any other javascript error. Are you seeing any error in your browser console ?

Comment: No, there is no error, post into database and everthing works fine, but redirects me to default view not to that i want to.

This is my complete javascript section: http://imgur.com/a/32tUl

Comment: **post into database** ?? In your question you wanted to redirect to the Index action on the submit button click ! If you fix the button id, It should work fine

Comment: Yes i have Azure SQL Database behind, where i store my data. I want to store my data and redirect me to other view, where i have displayed all of stored data. I changed id="redirect" but its not working...

Comment: If you have an action method which handles the form submit, you should do the redirect from your server code. But the code you posted has nothing other than a simple button and a click event handler and you were not able to make the click event handler work ! The posted answer should resolve that issue. Looks like you are having problem with some other piece of code which you did not share. It is hard for us to guess what it is , hence cannot help much :)

Comment: :/ Should i post Controller code or something else?

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)